# Diagnosis android actionbar (from picture)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to know which actionbar blackmart alpha app use?

here is a screen shot from its search view on search icon clicked:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PatzU.jpg

I want to use this actionbar because sherlock actionbar does not supoort search view in android 2.3 < devices.

If any one have a tutorial about how to create this actionbar with search view, it can really help me.

Answer (score 0):

You better user [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). It's a nice lib that provides backward compatibility down to Android 2.1 and mimics the Holo ActionBar that looks like this one in your screenshot. There's also plenty of documentation and questions and answers about it here in SO. Besides that, it's pretty reliable, and easy to use. Many famous apps use it.

Comment: Thank for your respond. ActionBarSherlock doesn't support searchview in android 2.3 and less. but blackmart alpha does support.

Comment: But you can use `actionBar.setCustomView(...)` And set your own EditText. I already did this and it worked.

Comment: It doesn't look like very nice with edit text. I want to use the standard source like the picture. Can you give me your edit text xml?

Comment: If you want that Holo look & feel, use HoloEverywhere: https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere